# Attic Skylight Install to Increase Sloped Ceiling Head Room

Tags: code-compliance, attic, skylight, clearance

I have an attic I'm considering converting to living space and looking at ways to increase light while also increasing head room. The current (skylight-less) roof has a slope and I'm wondering if I can install a bank of skylights, maybe raised up on a deck, to bring in some great views and increase head clearance below the skylights. I'm including a graphic showing the walking surface and the roof angle, along with a future raised skylight area. The stretch of walking surface in this area is about 15' long.

[image: Attic schematic]

Looking for people who have installed skylights in attics for the purposes of increasing head height/clearance.

If this is possible, wondering how I can make sure that rain/snow flows off the top side of the skylight. This would be especially important if I install a bank of skylights on a deck spanning the entire 15'.

Comment: You show the floor at 150". What's the wall height behind your little man? That's the truly important measurement.

Comment: If you are going through the trouble of cutting out all those rafters (and the additional engineering and gusseting required to add strength) you should consider adding *dormers* or a *gable and shed*.

Comment: @FreeMan it's not a good drawing. There's no wall there, the attic is open and an A shaped roof. The height of the ceiling at the apex of the roof is 102" or 8'6", which gives me a reasonable amount of space to get r49 for the top.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I was thinking of the dormer option, but I'm hoping to get specific information on the skylight option since it will be a DIY job, vs dormers which effectively puts it out of my reach.

Comment: I think that if you have the talent to cut out rafters, frame up an opening, and properly install, flash, and seal a skylight then you could do it. All the same basic tools and skills.

Comment: I think you're right, but my wife senses my apprehension of going the dormer route, so either I have to be a better liar, or I have to completely convince myself that it's a dormer or nothing. Part of the latter is this thread, hoping there's a few people out there that have used a bank of skylights to increase head room in an attic. If not, then dormer it is!

Comment: Find and binge-watch about 5 seasons of _This Old House_ from the early- to mid-90s. Long before the internet, that was all the education my wife & I had before we tackled building an _attached_ garage on our hose. In 28 years, we've only had leaks where we couldn't get the furnace vent to properly seal through the flashing. It took about 2 years of fiddling to get that right. Your solution - don't put any holes in the dormer roof!

Answer (score 0):

The Code requires a minimum ceiling height of 7’-0” for habitable spaces, unless 1) it’s a slopped ceiling, 2) basement remodel, 3) bathroom or shower. (See ICC R304.1)

1. Slopped ceilings shall have at least 50% with at least 7’ and slope down to no more than 5’.
2. Basements can have 6’-8” ceilings in non-habitable spaces.
3. Not more than 75% of a sloped ceiling in a bathroom can be less than 7’ if a space in front of toilet, sink, shower is 6’-4” high.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you explain which of my questions are answered by this answer?

Comment: Depending on your situation, you’ll need to comply with the code required height dimensions. Currently it does not comply, as pointed out in item 1.

Comment: Item 1 only means that anything below 5' isn't counted into the calculation of square footage for the room, which isn't something I'm concerned with at all.

Comment: The code doesn’t say not to count square footage when ceiling is less than 5’. It says habitable rooms can’t have spaces less than 5’ high. Maybe you could build a wall at the 5’ height. (If that space is only a hallway, storage space, closet, etc. then it’s not a habitable space. Add a desk, chair, bed, etc. in that space and it becomes a habitable space and is not allowed.)

Comment: Here's a good explanation of the knee wall issue, which isn't something I'm worried about (we will have crawl spaces and put in storage in most short ceiling areas)

https://evstudio.com/how-low-can-you-go-ceiling-heights-in-the-building-code/